# CSF file is not loading properly in the Azure Dataflow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am having a CSV file and trying to load it into dataflow for the transformation. However, when I checked the preview in the dataflow, my columns values are jumbled and did not appear properly.

I am able to open the CSV file in excel without any issue and below is the sample
[image]

Below is the output I am getting in the dataflow

[image]

I have other columns and it is getting jumbled

Can anyone advise how to rectify this issue? My csv file size is 257 MB.

Comment: Hi, do you have commas within the data in other columns? Can you show how the data from the data flow snip is shown in your CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling multiline rows. You can find it in Source Options.

[image: Source Options]